# open several text files one by one and read a specific string from each pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have several .txt files that i would like to open one by one and read the complete line of where i find a string and write that string to a separate .txt file.

This is what I have but pd.read_csv() doesn't like the list of files:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os 

file_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),folder_name,"*.txt"))

for file_path in file_list:
  with open(file_path, 'w+') as file:
    rowsOfLines = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None)
    for index, row in rowsOfLines.iterrows():
        splitLine = row.str.split()[0]
        if 'SN' in splitLine:
            file.write('{} \n'.format(splitLine))
        elif 'Raw_AI' in splitLine:
            file.write('{} \n'.format(splitLine))
        elif 'Final_AI' in splitLine:
            file.write('{} \n'.format(splitLine))
        elif 'ALL' in splitLine:
            file.write('{} \n'.format(splitLine))
```

I get a list of the complete path and file name in file_list but pd.read_csv() doesn't like it.

Comment: pd.read_csv opens and closes the file. You don't need your with statement.

Comment: Hi Ben.  Thanks.  But then how would I open the next file in the list to read its contents? I have several files that I need to open and read.

Comment: The next for loop would do that for you. The real issue you have though is that when you import a file with pd.read_csv(), the only way to get it to write to a csv is by using pd.to_csv(). Pandas will not "write" the original file using read_csv(). So you have really two choices, either use the structure you have and don't use pandas, or use pandas, manipulate the df's then export to new csv's. I, however, recommend looking at Dask. You can import them all with one line, manipulate them all, then export them all again with one line (again though, as new files).